# Developing a model to approximate an unknown score from known scores

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

*Apologies if this would be better suited elsewhere, this is the SE I was recommended. I can delete / move if needed.*

The target is to approximate a hidden rank in a game (Dota 2 if anyone is interested), using a visible rank (since there are 2, one for ranked games and one for unranked games, it is the unranked one that is hidden).

We can see the visible rank (which is a group of scores (called MMR)) freely and extract that from a website. We can see what MMR limits each group corresponds to, from another website, and the limits are sufficiently close together to be a fairly accurate approximation (e.g. 2000-2150). Assuming the game tries to match your team of 5 (which could be any rank each) against a roughly even MMR team of 5 (which could also be any rank each), and tries to retain a 50% Win / Loss rate. It will also try (though not always successfully) to match each person to an equivalent MMR person, but not sure that matters.

**Assumptions that can be made:**

- Enemy's displayed rank is close to their current rank
- The limit of the rank catogeries are sufficiently close to one another to be an accurate approximation
- Every win or loss grants + or - 25 MMR (Obviously needed for any win rate that deviates from 50%)
- MMR is roughly a normal distribution (of which each rank is a small segment of)
- There is enough data available to get a sufficiently large sample size

**Question:**

> How do I put this together to make a formula I can program, that takes
>   a single friendly player's win rates and visible rank, and enemy
>   player's win rates and visible rank to return the friendly player's
>   hidden rank

**Other thoughts:**

- Would some sort of weighting factor be required if the friendly
  player is particularly far apart in MMR from the rest of their party
  which might cause an uncommonly high number of wins or losses, and
  what would this weighting factor look like if needed?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Let me summarize: each player has a visible rank called MMR which is a nonnegative integer and also a hidden rank which is also a nonegative integer. The visible rank is the only information you have about other players (friendly or not). You assume that both ranks are "close" in some sense. The MMR is computed from the win/loss rates of the ranked games. 
Q1. Why do you need an enemy's rank for the hidden rank? Do you want to have an estimation partially based on the matchmaking?
Q2. Do you want to guess the hidden rank as a number or the category it falls into? (like Herald, Guardian etc.)

Comment: Yes... That's a much more succinct way of putting it. 
Q1) Enemies are matched against you in a skill based match making system. The MMR of your enemies suggests the MMR of yourself. Whereas the MMR of your allies could just be friends you've decided to play with, and there's no limiting factor on that.
Q2) I'd prefer number. But either. You can use the catogery to suggest a fairly small boundary for the number, using the data here: https://dota.rgp.io/mmr/

Comment: and here: https://pages.firstblood.io/pages/blog/dota-2/dota-2-ranking-system/

Comment: Q3. Does the matchmaking system take your hidden rank into account?

Comment: It does in a normal game where it usesyour hidden rank. Not in a ranked game, where it uses the visible rank. But you can make the reasonable assumption that most people's hidden rank and visible ranks are similar